# How do I go to the first search result in a file?

Tags: vim

Is there a command in vim for navigating to the first search result in a file (i.e. the one with the lowest line number)? Say, if I do `/foo`, can I find the first instance of `foo` in the file (not starting from where I am in the file, but starting from the beginning of the file)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`ggn` will bring you to the first instance of your search in the file -- the `gg` brings you the beginning of the file and the `n` goes to the next match of your pattern.

You can also use `gg2n` to go to the second instance in the file, or `gg42n` to go to the forty-second instance. You can similarly use `G$N` to go to the final match (`G` brings you to the final line, `$` brings you to the end of that line, and `N` searches backwards), or `G$2N` to go to the penultimate one.

Comment: I find `G$N` slightly awkward to type. Instead just do `ggN` and obviously if you already did `ggn` to be on the first result and want to hit the last result do `N`.

Comment: note if you are searching backwards this will give you the last result in the file... which makes sense but just confused me, forgot I'd pressed #!!

Comment: There is mush simpler `gD` command. suggested by @Ben below;

Answer (score 12):

Obscure Ex commands for the win:

```
:ij[ump] foo  "jumps to first foo that is not in a comment
:ij[ump]! foo "jumps to first foo, comment or not
```

See also `:il[ist]`.

Comment: +1 that *is* obscure! You can also use `:ij 2 foo` to go to the second one, etc.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that command! Any idea how to get to the *last* occurrence?

Comment: @PhilippMoers, do `:ilist` and choose the last occurrence.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I want. I want a non-interactive keybinding that immediately jumps to the last occurrence of the latest search term (like `G$N` does, but without polluting the jumplist). For the first occurrence, I have `nmap gö :ijump! 1 /<C-R>/<CR>`, but I can't figure out the same thing for the last occurrence.

Comment: `:ijump` uses a number which will always be different so I'm afraid there's no "easy" way to get what you want. You should try with a function that grabs the output of `:ilist` and parses it to get the number of the last occurrence.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `gg` command to navigate to the beginning of the file.

```
gg

/foo
```

Answer (score 4):

The gD command will search from the top of the file for the word under the cursor.

The related gd command will search from the top of the current c-like function.

Comment: This only works for words recognized as a "variable", not for arbitrary words. Ref: help gD

Answer (score 3):

Another cool shortcut if your cursor is on one of the matches in the file:

```
[<C-i>
```

(Just to be clear that's the left bracket ([) followed by control-i)

This is like using the "*" command but having it go to the first match in the file rather than the next match after the cursor

Comment: Oof. That's quite a key combination!  But thanks - I've been looking for this!

Answer (score 2):

This is rather too late, but the answer may help someone. This is not a command to be executed inside vim, rather passing the search word as an argument while opening the file from linux command line.
type `vi filename +/foo` on linux command line. vi will open the file directly to line where the first occurrence of the word 'foo' is.

Answer (score 1):

Methods relying on using `gg` and then searching through either `/foo` or `n` are fine for interactive use, but when batch editing with Vim's `-S` argument they won't work if the searched word is the first word in the file; in that case your cursor will be positioned at the second occurence.

The foolproof method is an ex command `:0/foo`. Issuing only an address in ex command will take you to that address, so `:12` will take you to the twelfth line. ed/ex/Vim support search patterns as addresses, so `:/foo` will take you to the first match from the cursor position (implicit "." at the beginning). `:0/foo` means "first 'foo' from the zero'th line".

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Your answer could be made more complete by including an example and some additional explanation about the proposed command. Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

Real late here but in case this helps someone, I think the "POSIX" way to "jump" to the first match with a "proper" `vi` or `ex` (no *vim*-like extensions required) is closer to:

`:1;/foo/;`

Start on line 1

From there, find to the first line containing pattern *foo*

Then repeat the pattern search (on that same line) by using `;`.

`ex` is expected to work on characters (not lines) and open at the end of a file by default.

Likewise, something like this is more POSIX
Recall that `vi` is supposed to work on lines and open on the first row by default.

`$ vi "+/foo/;" file.txt`

These should jump you to the first character of the first occurrence of *foo*, no matter where you are in the buffer / file even without "*vim* powers."

You might need something more along the lines of ~

```
:set searchincr
:1;/foo/;/
```

Another method ~

```
:1^M/foo
```

`^M` is a literal input using `<control>+v` then `<enter/return>`
You might need to play with it to meet the requirements of your implementation.

YMMV